# how to run Bool function if if statement is true

Tags: c++

```
bool isTriangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC){
if(sideA + sideB > sideC && sideA + sideC > sideB && sideB + sideC > sideA){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}

int main() {
double sideA, sideB, sideC;

cout << "Enter the lengths of the three sides of a triangle -- ";
cin >> sideA >> sideB >> sideC;

if (&isTriangle){
    if(sideA != sideB && sideB != sideC){
        cout << "This is a scalene";
    }
    isEquilateral(sideA, sideB, sideC);
    isIsosceles(sideA, sideB, sideC);
    isRight(sideA,sideB,sideC);
    
    cout << "Its perimeter is " << per << endl;
}
if(!&isTriangle){
    cout << "This is not a triangle" << endl;
}
```

}

How can I run code when an if statement inside the bool function is true.I have my bool function and it test the triangle sides and checks if it is a triangle, if it is, it returns true, if not it returns false. If it's true I want to run my other functions, if it's not a triangle I just want to display a message.

Comment: `&isTriangle` will always be true, did you mean to call the function instead?

Comment: If you have something like `if (condition) return true; else return false;` then that's exactly equal to `return condition;`. Also, if you have `if (condition) { ... } if (!condition) { ... }` then that's almost always the same as `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: You call it in the same way as you call your other functions. (And your other functions should probably also return `bool` and not have their return values ignored.)

Comment: As for your problem, you know how to call functions (you do it with e.g. `isEquilateral`). Why can't you do it with `isTriangle`?

Comment: There's also the matter of the seemingly undefined `per` variable. Is it a global variable? If it is, then why is it a global variable? Putting it all together it seems you lack some very basic C++ knowledge, perhaps from skipping classes or sections or even chapters in text-books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
if (&isTriangle){
```

should be this

```
if (isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC)){
```

When you call a function, you use the name of that function followed by parentheses `()` and you put the parameters that the function requires inside the parentheses separated by commas.

Some other suggestions.

If you want to test something and do one thing if it is true and another thing if it is false. Then the way to do this is with `if ... else ...`. Like this

```
 if (isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC)) {
     ...
 }
 else {
     ...
 }
```

It's not so good to use two `if ...` and repeat the test, like you are doing

```
 if (isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC)) {
     ...
 }
 if (!isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC)) { // repeated test
     ...
 }
```

When you have code like this `if (something) return true; else return false;` you can skip the if statement and just say `return something;`. In other words there's no need to say 'if something is true then return true and if something is false return false' you can just say 'return something'. So this code

```
if(sideA + sideB > sideC && sideA + sideC > sideB && sideB + sideC > sideA){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

can be rewritten more simply as

```
return sideA + sideB > sideC && sideA + sideC > sideB && sideB + sideC > sideA;
```